# SF2 and sonata admin, cannot see my Admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I want to use the SoanatAdminBundle with my User entity. I generate an AdminBundle, i want all the administration code in there.

When i go to localhost/app_dev.php/admin i see the sonata dashboard but i don't see my users list.

Service.xml (AdminBundle)

```
<services>
    <service id="admin.user" class="WebSite\AdminBundle\Admin\UserAdmin">
      <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="admin" label="User"/>
        <argument />
        <argument>Website\UserBundle\Entity\User</argument>
        <argument>SonataAdminBundle:CRUD</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

UserAdmin (AdminBundle\Admin\UserAdmin.php)

```
class UserAdmin extends Admin
{
       .... // Everything is ok
}
```

config.yml:

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        groups:
            admin.group.content:
                label: admin.group.content
                label_catalogue: AdminBundle
                items:
                    - admin.user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replace:

```
handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role
```

by

```
handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.noop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        groups:
            admin: ~
```

Comment: Didn't work. I had to put ```handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.noop``` in my security conf

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the admin is registered in the Dependency Container: `app/console container:debug | grep admin.user`. If nothing appear then the related file is not included in your extension.